# I Want to add a video in my html5 website

Tags: html, html5-canvas, html5-video

In my html 5 website i want to add a video , i tried every possible way but its not working.. can anyone tell me the proper way of embedding video in html 5 ....

Comment: be careful with copy paste.. However, you can google it..

Comment: Try searching Google. Or if you are having concrete issues, describe them in more details

Comment: Nothing is working  that is why i asked it here

Comment: Post what you've tried, what you expected, and what happened. Otherwise we're just guessing and we're not telepathic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
       <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Answer (score 2):

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp
Take a look.. Everything basic you need is here..

A simple google search would have sufficed.